# Receiving data both from Wi-Fi and LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, wifi-configuration, connection-sharing

I live in a structure where we have a limited download speed (`3Mbps`) per device due the "large population" in there, so i was wondering if it's possible to put together phone and pc download speeds. In Android I can share the Wi-Fi connection through USB Tethering. Is there a way to tell my pc to download both from LAN and Wi-Fi?

Comment: Unfortunately, no way.

Comment: I've never done it for this purpose, but there is a software solution that lets you route certain apps out of certain NICs, but this will give you 3Mbps from each NIC not a total through put of 6Mbps but the hassle may not be worth it.  https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip

Comment: What OS is the computer running? What software are you using for downloads? Are you downloading from the internet, or from another system in the same LAN?